# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not sourced from .bashrc when sudo -iu bob /opt/builder/bin/start.sh on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-20.04

I have recently migrated from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. When I'm trying to start the script it seems that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not sourced from users `.bashrc`.

The way that I'm executing the command is
`sudo -iu bob /opt/builder/bin/start.sh`

My `.bashrc` contains `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:`

My `~/.bash_profile` as well as `~/.profile` are sourcing `~/.bashrc`

`/etc/sudoers` is identical as on Ubuntu 16.04

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Nothing is being included from `sudoers.d`.

Have any one seen such behaviour? I know that solution might be to add `source ~/.bashrc` in `start.sh` but I'm sure there is a system wide solution for the changed behaviour.

Comment: Is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in bob's `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or `.profile`? You're running the command in a login shell (`sudo -i`) of a different user, or is it user `bob` running the command too?

Comment: @frippe The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in `.bashrc` but the `.bash_profile` and `.profile` are sourcing `.bashrc`. I'm running the command `sudo -iu` as `root`

Comment: If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set only for `root` and not for `bob`, it won't be set when you run the script in a login shell for a different user (i.e., `bob`). You can either set the environment variable in `bob`'s shell start-up script(s) or invoke `sudo` with the `-E` flag to preserve the environment (this can't be used with `-i`),

Comment: @frippe `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set for `root` at all. It's only set for `bob`

Comment: What makes you think `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't set? Have you confirmed that the variable is indeed unset? What is `bob`'s default shell?

Comment: @frippe When I do `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as `root` I get an empty response. When I run the script with `sudo -iu bob` I have added the first line to `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> /tmp/a` it's empty plus the builder return error that the library cannot be found. When I switch to `bob` and run it all works fine. The default shell is `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

The default `.bashrc` has a check at the very top of the script to check if it's being run from an interactive shell. If it's not, it won't run.

The man-page for `bash` says that:

> An  interactive  shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option[...]

From the documentation on the `-i` option of the `sudo` command:

> If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.

That means `sudo -iu bob /opt/builder/bin/start.sh` is run in a non-interactive login shell, meaning `.bashrc` will return early and never reach the part where you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You may also want to not have leading and/or trailing `:` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. That will make `ld` look for libraries in the current directory, which may be exploited.